# How to fix 'error :unexpected in " ' that appears in submit a R task with spark-submit

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

The problem is when I want to submit a Rscript to my spark Cluster by spark-submit or sparkR,and console shows like that:

```
Error: unexpected input in
Execution halted
```

The condition is I have a spark cluster and I configured R in every server, R code can run in rconsole, but when I submit r code, it looks like something is wrong.

Here's the code

```
library(SparkR)  
sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local")  
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
localDF <- data.frame(name=c("John", "Smith", "Sarah"), age=c(19, 23, 18))  
df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, localDF)    
printSchema(df)   
sparkR.stop()
```